# Android iterate array inside array

Tags: android, arrays, json

I have an json array from webservice connection. I want to iterate to an array objects that are columns of a table and data of a table. Array is like below:

```
"Table":{
"Columns":[
"ItemCode",
"Description",
"Value"
],
"Data":[{"itemCode": "01", "description": "data", "value": "val"]
}
```

I am doing:

```
JSONArray list = obj.getJSONArray("Table");
        for(int i = 0; i < list.length(); i++){
            JSONArray data = list.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("Columns");
            for(int j=0;j<data.length(); j++){
                data.getString(i);

            }
        }
```

But it displays:

> org.json.JSONException: Valueat Table of type org.json.JSONObject
>   cannot be converted to JSONArray

Comment: Your error itself told that `JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray`. your "Table" data is JSONObject type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "Table" is a `JSONObject`. You should be doing like,

```
JSONObject list = obj.getJSONObject("Table");

JSONArray data = list.getJSONArray("Columns");
```

Comment: getJSONObject(i) in JSONObject cannot be applied